# CRF in tensorflow keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I know that Keras-contrib is deprecated and has been migrated to tensorflow/addons, but I don't understand how can I add a CRF layer using this new library.

Does anyone know which tensorflow/addons feature is the equivalent to the keras-contrib CRF layer ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use TensorFlow Addons(`tfa`). In your case use `tfa.layers.CRF`.

To use the above, first you have to install the latest version as shown below

```
pip install tensorflow-addons
```

You can use addons as shown below

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
from tensorflow_addons.layers import CRF
```

For more information you can refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/layers/CRF)